# converting from int to (16-bit) __m128i

Tags: c, x86, simd, sse3

I have the following code as a part of a program, but when I compile it I get the following error:

```
cannot convert ‘int’ to ‘__m128i {aka __vector(2) long long int}’ in assignment
```

Where the code is:

```
int t;
int s;
__m128i *array;
__m128i vector;

posix_memalign ((void **) &array, BYTE_ALIGNMENT, n * m * sizeof(__m128i) );

int l=0;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
  {
    array[l] = (condition) ? t : s;   // fill the array elements with s or t 
    l++;
  }
}
vector = _mm_load_si128( &array[index]);
```

The problem is in this line

```
array[l] = (condition) ? t : s;
```

I have found the instruction `__m128i _mm_cvtsi32_si128(int a)` but unfortunately, it is used for 32-bits elements only, while I have  16-bit elements (vector of size 8).

Comment: Have you tried using an explicit cast to type `__m128i`?

Comment: Do you mean like that?
    array[l] = (condition) ? (__m128i) t : (__m128i) s; 

It gives me the following error :
error: can’t convert between vector values of different size

Comment: Are you looking for something like: `_mm_set1_epi16()`

Comment: Not exactly,  because the set instruction fills the whole vector. While I want to set one element in the vector through every loop based on the condition in the IF statement

Comment: In another words, I would like to fill the array elements individually based on an IF statement; during the FOR loops. Then load the array to a vector ...While the set instruction will fill the whole array with a static values

Comment: Are `s` and `t` constant ? And what are the inputs to the `condition` test, i.e. what does `if (condition)` depend on ?

Comment: S and T are input variables, and the condition depends on another variables. But we can say that if the condition happens the array [l]=T .. else =S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i found this update is working properly

```
int t;
int s;
int16_t *array;
__m128i vector;

posix_memalign ((void **) &array, BYTE_ALIGNMENT, n * m * sizeof(int16_t) );

int l=0;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
  {
    array[l] = (condition) ? t : s;   // fill the array elements with s or t 
    l++;
  }
}
vector = _mm_load_si128( (__m128i*)&array[index]);
```

Thanks for you all

Comment: Oh - so you didn't even want to vectorise the code ? You were just trying to fix a syntax error ? My bad...